# Remove parent div of modal jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to delete the parent `div` of a modal by clicking the delete `button`. I have a page with `div` with `class="p"` and I want to remove them when I submit a form via my `modal`.

Below is the code

```
  <div class="p">
    The first div with class p
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="delete"> Remove <button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <div>

 <div class="p">
    The second div with class p
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <button class="delete"> Remove <button>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <div>
```

I am trying to remove the `div` with `class="p"` when I click on the `button` but I cannot manage to do so, right now I am using:

```
$('.delete').on("submit", function (e) {
    var modal = $(this).closest('#modal-delete');
    $(modal).find('.p').parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Firstly you are saying to remove parent `<div>` with clicking on delete button, but after that are you saying to delete them when submitting the form ? What actually you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contents()` and `replaceWith()` method to remove the parent element except for its child element.

```
$('.delete').on("submit", function (e) {
    var content = $("div.p").contents(); 
    $("div.p").replaceWith(content); 
});
```

Or another way is use `unwrap()` method :

```
$('.delete').on("submit", function (e) {
    $("div.p").contents().unwrap();
});
```